# TbGridView with DatePicker not displaying on second row in yii

Tags: gridview, yii, datepicker

I'm not sure why this happening. I want to display the date picker in each row, but the gridview only displays the first row (both from and to displays). After that, the calendar never shows up (both from and to). [image]

```
public function saleDateFrom()
{
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
            'name'=>'product_discount_valid_from',
            'value'=>date('d-m-Y'),
    ));

}
```

and where the grid is:

```
'columns'=>array(
            array('name'=>'product_name', 'header'=>'Product Name','htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'300')),
            array(
                    'value'=>array($this,'saleDateFrom'),
                    'header'=>'Valid From',
                    'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'150'),
                    ),
```

Comment: I think it has id conflicts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the ID's of the generated input fields. Your sateDateFrom function will generate an input field with an id of 'product_discount_valid_from', and so the following rows conflict, and the javascript ends up not knowing which element to attach to.

To cure this, you need to create unique ids for each element generated by the sateDateFrom() function. Inside this function, because it is called from the grid, you have two variables automatically available to it it; $data and $row. These can be used to create unique ids. So try changing your function to something like this;

```
public function saleDateFrom($data, $row)
{
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
            'name'=>'product_discount_valid_from',
            'value'=>date('d-m-Y'),
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                  'id' => 'product_discount_valid_from_' . $row
                  'class' => 'addDatePicker'
            ),
    ));

}
```

You can then use the addDatePicker class to add a datepicker to all elements having that class.